# how to Send sms with a url using twilio?

Tags: apex, url, sms, twilio

I am using Twilio Rest Api to send sms from my salesforce app to a particular phone number. The sms is sending fine, but there is a big url in the sms body. When I open the sms in my phone, only a part of the url is detected as a link in the sms (to be exact, until the first space in the url). This is the code I used:

```
        String params = '/?cType=consent&patientId='+ patientId +'&patientName='+ patientName +'&physicianName=' + uInfo.Name +'&physicianAddress=' + uInfo.DoctorAddress__c;
        String messageBody = siteUrl + params;
                   
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+twilioAccountSid+'/Messages.json');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('X-Twilio-Client', 'salesforce-2010-04-01');
        req.setHeader('User-Agent', 'twilio-salesforce-2010-04-01');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', '"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+ EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(twilioAccountSid + ':' + twilioAuthToken)));
        req.setBody('Body=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(messageBody, 'UTF-8')
               + '&From=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(fromNumber, 'UTF-8')
               + '&To=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(toNumber, 'UTF-8'));
        HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

**I want the whole url to be detected as a link in the Messaging app in my phone, and when I click on the url, browser should be opened with the url.**

I have tried  using `EncodingUtil.urlEncode(params, 'UTF-8')`. But, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use BitlyService to shorten url. No need to use EncodingUtil.urlEncode for parameters. I have implemented and it is working fine for me.

```
 BitlyService bitly=new BitlyService();
    string shortUrl=bitly.shorten(url);
    if(string.isNotBlank(shortUrl))
    {
       string smsBody='Please click link: '+shortUrl;
       //method call to send SMS
       SMSService.send('+1'+mobile,smsBody);
    }
```

create named credential **Bitly** for using callout.

```
** Bitly url shortener service.  */
public class BitlyService {     
    private String accessToken;            
    public BitlyService() 
    {    
        this.accessToken = getAccessToken();
    }
    public String shorten( String url ) 
    {   
        this.accessToken='****** Your token';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Bitly/v3/shorten' + '?access_token=' + this.accessToken + '&longUrl=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(url, 'UTF-8') + '&format=txt');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
    }
    private String getAccessToken() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Bitly/oauth/access_token');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
    }
}
```

Comment: i used [Rebrandly](https://www.rebrandly.com/)  to shorten the url. But, it still is throwing exception 'Url entered is not valid'. I think, the space in the url is creating problems.

Comment: What URL is showing for messageBody? Check with hardcoding URL.